# how print values 0-255 depend on ASCII code

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

python--i work in encryption image so i want to convert each value in image to character.
the values are between (0-255)
i use this code below

```
for i in range(130,150):
s=chr(i)
print(i,s)
```

the o/p are character like rectangular shape
the o/p for all range values are not the same char in ASCII table
i want o/p like ASCII code [enter link description here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjyp9b29cjhAhWSCOwKHT3HD2gQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.commfront.com%2Fpages%2Fascii-chart&psig=AOvVaw3piYVAZz86LnbWwzNLctv6&ust=1555102355495886)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: thanks u can try to run code

Comment: Indentation is not optional in Python.

Comment: A rectangular shape is shown when a font does not have a glyph for the character. The output could well be as you intend but your renderer (terminal?) just is not showing it the way you want. To verify send the output to a file and check the bytes.

Comment: But, why not use Base64 to represent non-text data as text instead of a character encoding?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want, but your code does not work because of your indentation. Try this:

```
for i in range(130, 150):
  s = chr(i)
  print (i, s)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but I guess this's what you want:-

```
in Python2: str(unichr(97))
in Python3: str(chr(97))
```

i.e. gives 'a'

**Also your indentation is wrong !!**

```
for i in range(130, 150):
  s = str(chr(i))
  print (i, s)
```